# Using the densest galactic superclusters motion to see a universal structure or motion

Tags: physics, astrophysics

My alien species has their science and observation based on our current understandings and observations, they have an observabe universe of the same distance as ours
they have noticed the structure and behaviour of the densest galactic superclusters in their closest observable universe, the equivelent for our univese would be the densities of of the Draco, Shapley, Horologium and Virgo superclusters. creating a pattern of gravitational pull and organisation from their arrangement.

My question is: From their 3 billion lightyear mapping of distribution and flows, can a larger scale organisation and flow be derived or should things at such a scale be considered as localised and contributing to a larger scale pattern or motion?

Comment: Are you asking whether the movement/flow of galactic clusters in the observable universe can be used to infer the distribution of other sorts of structures beyond the observable universe?

Comment: I'm now fascinated as to what happened here to warrant the OP getting 12 month suspension from the site rather than an outright ban. Did one of the mods accidentally hit 22 for the year instead of the day?

Comment: @Starfish prime In British slang of the nineteen seventies , it's a 'nudge, nudge, wink wink, say no more' sort of situation. You had to be there. (Deleted comments pertain). Bless the mods and all who sail in them.

Answer (score 3):

I have interpreted your question as "can we use the movement of superclusters at the edge of the observable universe to infer the structure of the external (unobservable) universe," so my answer is based on that. Let me know if I've interpreted it incorrectly.

I'm not an expert, but I'll try to use basic reasoning to answer.

We can't assume that the motion of super distant galaxies is a result of extra-observable forces. If galaxy A lies inside the observable universe and galaxy B lies outside, then in order for galaxy A to have a relative motion towards B due to gravity, gravity must propagate from B to A. Alongside gravity, light from B will also have propagated from B to A.
Now, in order for us to perceive this change in relative motion of A, light from A will have had to propagate to us at the center of the observable universe. However, because light from B has already reached A, and because the change in motion didn't occur until light from B reached A, to see A move as a result of B's influence, we will also have to see light from B.
Essentially, we can't see the influence of things outside the observable universe without also being able to see those things via light, thus making them no longer "outside" the observable universe.